# Upgrade to 1.9.3.3 causing configurable products to have no add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I've recently upgraded a site from 1.9.1.1 to  1.9.3.3. Everything went well and as expected except for one critical issue. Configurable products are not showing the options or add to cart buttons. (The 'product-options' div and 'product-options-bottom' are not rendering).

I'm pulling my hair out and have tried everything that I could think of. Simple products works fine. I haven't changed any configurations in admin or amended any template phtml files.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

[image: Problem]

This is how it is looking currently ^^

and this is how it should look:

[image]